# Match to second regular expression if first has no matches

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to extract the text between HTML tags using regex in python.  The catch is that **sometimes there are no HTML tags in the string**, so I want my regex to match the entire string.  So far, I've got the part that matches the inner text of the tag:

```
(?<=>).*(?=<\/)
```

This would match to Russia in the tag below

```
<a density="sparse" href="http://topics.bloomberg.com/russia/">Russia</a>
```

Alternately, the entire string would be matched:

```
Typhoon Vongfong prompted ANA to cancel 101 flights, affecting about 16,600 passengers, the airline said in a faxed statement. Japan Airlines halted 31 flights today and three tomorrow, it said by fax. The storm turned northeast after crossing Okinawa, Japan’s southernmost prefecture, with winds gusting to 75 knots (140 kilometers per hour), according to the U.S. Navy’s Joint Typhoon Warning Center.
```

Otherwise I want it to return all the text in the string.

I've read a bit about regex conditionals online, but I can't seem to get them to work.  If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: post an example along with the expected output.

Comment: use some html parsers. [Beautifulsoup for example](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Why don't you use `if-else` ?

Comment: I'm trying to learn regex, but if it can't be done, I'll go to that option.

Comment: @superlizardmo a single example wouldn't be enough. Post an example which satisfies all your requirements along with the expected output..

Comment: HTML parsing is not the ideal place to learn regular expressions.

Comment: To get to this point, I've used BeautifulSoup to extract all the tags and I've got the article I'm parsing into an array, the problem is that some elements are tags and some are sections of text. I'm running the regex anyway and I'm looking for any way to do this in one step

Comment: @superlizardmo this one http://regex101.com/r/sD4pC7/3

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a single regex. You don't need to go for any workaround.

```
>>> import re
>>> s='<a density="sparse" href="http://topics.bloomberg.com/russia/">Russia</a>'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=>)[^<>]+(?=</)|^(?!.*?>.*?</).*', s, re.M)
['Russia']
>>> s='This is Russia Today'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=>)[^<>]+(?=</)|^(?!.*?>.*?</).*', s, re.M)
['This is Russia Today']
```

Comment: +1, but I would use `re.S` instead of `re.M` because OP want entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work-around.  Instead of adjusting the regex, we adjust the string:

```
>>> s='<a density="sparse" href="http://topics.bloomberg.com/russia/">Russia</a>'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=>)[^<>]*(?=<\/)', s if '>' in s else '>%s</' % s)
['Russia']
>>> s='This is Russia Today'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=>)[^<>]*(?=<\/)', s if '>' in s else '>%s</' % s)
['This is Russia Today']
```